# How to automate enter key press event in Appium for Android

Tags: android, automation, appium, android-testing

I'm not able to automate enter key event in Appium. I tried below logics

```
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for automating Enter Key in Android

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;

    driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code. This is tested and passed in the current latest io.appium/java-client 7.3.0.

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;



((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```